# simple ruby calculator webpage, how to store temporary variables and process them on the same page with submit

Tags: ruby, variables, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a simple page that will do simple calculations and return them on the same page. Ultimately i'll learn to use javascript and/or ajax to call them without reloading the entire page, but I'm new to programming so i'm trying to take incremental steps to get there.

I have been able to create the form and submit it with no errors. The result returns '0' and *I think* it's because when the page gets submitted and returns the same 'index' page it clears the instance variable. I have a few question:

1. How can I get the variable @result to actually return the result (and is this a good way of going about it?) and
2. Is it possible to load the result in the Vdrop number field?
3. In the future I want to be able to dynamically add rows (that include each variable, amps, volts, etc.) which would mean I would want to run the calculation more than once. I would assume I need to use some sort of "@variable do |f| 1..n" type of formula correct?

Thanks for help in advance!

Here's my controller code:

```
class CalculatorController < ApplicationController

def calculate
   amps = params[:amps].to_i
   volts = params[:volts].to_i
   distance = params[:distance].to_i
   phase = params[:phase].to_i
   @result = amps + volts + distance + phase
   render 'index'
end

end
```

Here's my index.html.erb code for the calculator page:

```
<div class="calculator index">
    <h2>Calculator Test</h2>
<div>
    <table class="table table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th>Amps</th>
            <th>Volts</th>
            <th>Phase</th>
            <th>Distance</th>
            <th>VDrop</th>
        </tr>

  <%= form_tag({:controller => "calculator", :action => "calculate"}, :method => "post") do %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= number_field 'Amps' , :class => 'text_field', :step => 'any' %></td>
    <td><%= number_field 'Volts', :class => 'text_field', :step => 'any' %></td>
    <td><%= number_field 'Phase', :class => 'text_field', :step => 'any' %></td>
    <td><%= number_field 'Distance', :class => 'text_field', :step => 'any' %></td>
      <td><%= number_field 'Vdrop', :class => 'text_field', :step => 'any' %></td>
    </tr> 

    </table>
     <%= submit_tag('Submit')%>
</div>
<div>
     <%= @result %>
</div>

<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "actually return the result"?

Comment: I'm trying to return the @return instance varaible result i.e.: '@result = amps + volts + distance + phase'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you're trying to pass instance variables, which are instances of that action to other actions cause technically the index.html.erb template is being rendered due to the index action which you don't have. What I'd do is:

```
class CalculatorController < ApplicationController

def index
   if params[:amps]
     amps = params[:amps].to_i
     volts = params[:volts].to_i
     distance = params[:distance].to_i
     phase = params[:phase].to_i
     @result = amps + volts + distance + phase
   else
     @result = "make a calculation"
   end
end

end
```

Your form:

```
<%= form_tag ({controller: 'calculators', action: 'index'}), method: :get do %>

    <td><%= number_field_tag :amps , nil %></td>
    <td><%= number_field_tag :volts, nil %></td>
    <td><%= number_field_tag :phase, nil %></td>
    <td><%= number_field_tag :distance, nil %></td>
      <td><%= number_field_tag :vdrop, nil %></td>
    <%= submit_tag('Submit')%>
<% end %>

   <%= @result %>
```

Will work. Just tried it.

Number of things to make it work: 1. it's number_field_tag not number_field. 2. try not to use `"AMPS"` for the params instead use `:amps`, the `if params[:amps]` wasn't detecting the `"AMPS"` unless i did `params["AMPS"]`

Controller is the same.

Comment: i replaced the code with what is provided and got a: "Showing C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/sites/solar_permit/app/views/calculator/index.html.erb where line #14 raised:" error. A question on the class controller - with the 'if params[:amps]' section, are you simply checking to see if there is actual data in that field? Also, I do not have a 'calculate.html.erb' page, just the index.html.erb pages...

Comment: the `if params[:amps]` is checking if you have anything in the params with that. and I cannot tell what line 14 is here

Comment: Make sure to change the action name to index not calculate

Comment: I get this error: The action 'show' could not be found for CalculatorController

Comment: I also get this error when i go to the index: undefined local variable or method `calculators_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000004847958>:0x00000005db90e8>

Comment: Try `<%= form_tag ({:controller => "calculator", :action => "index"}, :method => "get") %>`

Comment: SyntaxError in CalculatorController#index
C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/sites/solar_permit/app/views/calculator/index.html.erb:14: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' ...culators", :action => "index"}, :method => "get") );@output_... ... ^ C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/sites/solar_permit/app/views/calculator/index.html.erb:14: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end ...> "index"}, :method => "get") );@output_buffer.safe_append=' ... ^ C:/Users/Kevin/Desktop/sites/solar_permit/app/views/calculator/index.html.erb:32: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Comment: Now i get "The action 'create' could not be found for CalculatorController" (i had to change the controller name to singular)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, my hard drive crashed and I had to re-setup everything. Worked like a charm. Thanks for sticking with me on this one. I really appreciate it!! :)